# SCSS: Nested link :hover attribute not working?

Tags: html, css, sass

Trying to change the hover color to red but nothing is happening (last line):

```
.post-footer {
    &__links {
        a {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-left: $sp*2;
            
            &:link,
            &:visited {
                color: $footer-color-subheading;
            }
            &:hover {color: red;}
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the HTML for reference:

```
<div class="post-footer">
    <div class="post-footer__links">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">Link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code itself looks fine. Are you able to setup a codepen to take a look.

Comment: Are you sure the variables `$sp` and `$footer-color-subheading` are predefined? It could be the scss failed parsing because of undefined variables.

Comment: As @Pedz mentioned, there doesn't seem to be an issue with the code you've included in your question - I plopped it into codepen, swapped out the variables, and it worked fine. I'd suggest double-checking the variables and otherwise looking at other hover or A element styling upstream from where your example lives.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys, issue was I had to clear my browser cache

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses everyone -- The issue was I had to clear my browser cache so the css could update the page. My mistake.